# Can't import my .sof file to my FPGA

Tags: sensor, fpga, temperature, import

i am new to the whole VHDL/FPGA thing, and i am trying to import a simple AND gate to my [FPGA](https://makerselectronics.com/product/rz-easy-fpga-a2-2-development-board), but i get the failed message everytime, any idea how to fix it?

P.S : For some reason the device it detects is EP4CE15E22, instead of EP4CE6E22C8, which i tried to change to the correct one, but then when i would try to choose the file i want to import, it would roll me back to the wrong one.
Any ideas?

[image: Auto-Detecting the device]

[image: Failed import]

Comment: Sounds like you built your project for wrong chip, and that's why it switches back to this chip type. Load th eproject and check is Assignments -> Device.

Comment: You sir were right, it finally uploaded! Thank you very much!